# how to make gameobject transparent using slider in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make gameobject transparent using slider, but transparency could not work after writing the script. my shader setting is legacy standard/diffuse. so what changes should I make to this script? and also what setting I should make along with the script code. please help me out to work with the script.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class TransparentObject : MonoBehaviour
{
   private GameObject objectTotransparent;
   public float alpha = 0.3f;
   //private float increaseAlpha;
   //private float decreaseAlpha;
   public Slider transparentSlider;
   //renderer attached to the object that you want to make transparent
   //public Renderer rend;
   private Material currentMat;


   /*void Awake()
  {
    transparentSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderChanged);
  }*/

void Start()
{
    //objectTotransparent = gameObject;
    //currentMat = objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    AsistantControllScript = FindObjectOfType<AsistantControll>();

   currentMat = currentGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
}

void Update()
{
    //ChangeAlpha(currentMat, alpha);
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hitObject;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject))
        {
            objectTotransparent = 
             hitObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.gameObject;
            objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetSelected();
        }
    }
}

void ChangeAlpha(Material mat, float alphaVal)
{
    Color oldColor = mat.color;
    Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b, alphaVal);
    mat.SetColor("_Color", newColor);
}

public void ChangeAlphaOnValue(Slider slider)
{
    ChangeAlpha(currentMat, slider.value);
}

public void Deselect()
{
    objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetOriginalMaterial();
    objectTotransparent = null;
    transparentSlider.value = alpha;
} 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a slider that appears on the screen in the game, or just a slider in the Unity inspsector panel?

Comment: slider which appears on the screen in the game

Comment: Your code is ok, but cannot do transparency with a regular material, you need a special shader/material that supports transparency

Comment: Can u say what's that special shader/material

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterRenderingMode.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your material `Rendering Mode` into `Transparent`:

[image: Rendering mode]

Comment: My shader mode is legacy standards/diffuse

Comment: @ibrahim46 You need to change it to legacy transparent diffuse then. See this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-TransDiffuse.html

Comment: Still no changes